# adding "empty" rows to the query result

Tags: sql, oracle

i am really stuck with this task - i need to populate a report with rows with "0" values based on a particular criteria, here is the example:

lets say we have a table BROKERS with company names, their transaction types and cumulative amounts for a current month and all months ever.

```
COMPANY       TRAN_TYPE          CURR_MNTH         ALL_MNTH  
Broker1       CURRENCY_SELL      $1000.00          $1500000.00 
Broker1       GOLD_SELL          $50000.00         $2500000.00 
Broker1       GOLD_BUY           $80000.00         $8500000.00 
Broker1       STOCKS_SELL        $35000.00         $3500000.00
```

table BROKERS does not have a field TRAN_TYPE, but has a field TRAN_TYPE_CD which reffers to another table called TRAN_TYPE_CD_EXPL, where all the codes are explained:

```
TRAN_TYPE_CD  TRAN_TYPE_CD_EXPLD
1             STOCKS_SELL
2             STOCKS_BUY
3             GOLD_SELL
4             GOLD_BUY
5             SILVER_SELL
6             SILVER_BUY
7             COPPER_SELL
8             COPPER_BUY
9             CURRENCY_SELL
10            CURRENCY_BUY
```

so the results shown above is just a simple join of those two tables:

```
select  b.COMPANY, tt.TRAN_TYPE, b.CURR_MONTH, b.ALL_MNTH
from    BROKERS b, TRAN_TYPE_CD_EXPL tt
where   b.TRAN_TYPE_CD = tt.TRAN_TYPE_CD;
```

everything is pretty simple, but here is where the problem starts : the report i am working on should look like this:

```
COMPANY       MARKET      TRAN_TYPE          CURR_MNTH         ALL_MNTH  
Broker1       FOREX       CURRENCY_SELL      $1000.00          $1500000.00 
Broker1       FOREX       CURRENCY_BUY       $0.00             $5500000.00 
Broker1       CONTRACTS   GOLD_SELL          $50000.00         $2500000.00 
Broker1       CONTRACTS   GOLD_BUY           $80000.00         $8500000.00 
Broker1       STOCKMARKET STOCKS_SELL        $35000.00         $3500000.00 
Broker1       STOCKMARKET STOCKS_BUY         $0.00             $9500000.00
```

so let me explain : 
firstable, report should contains a column MARKET, which should be populated based on the values in the column TRAN_TYPE, but the thing is there is no table MARKET in database, so each time when you need to populate it in a report or somewhere else, you need to use decode like this (assumed everybody knows where all kind of tran_types belong to):

```
SELECT DECODE (TRAN_TYPE_CD_EXPL.TRAN_TYPE_CD_EXPLD,
             'CURRENCY_SELL', 'FOREX',
             'CURRENCY_BUY', 'FOREX',
             'STOCKS_SELL', 'STOCKMARKET',
             'STOCKS_BUY', 'STOCKMARKET') AS MARKET,
```

or based on TRAN_TYPE_CD value:

```
SELECT DECODE (BROKERS.TRAN_TYPE_CD,
             9, 'FOREX',
             10, 'FOREX',
             1, 'STOCKMARKET',
             2, 'STOCKMARKET') AS MARKET,
```

2) problem number 2 is more complicated : the report logic says - is a company has at least one transaction in a particular group (lets say CURRENCY_SELL for market type 'FOREX'), the report should be populated with other tran_types from the market type group with $0 even thou this company did not have any of those transactions during current month. so in this case it should be populated with the rows

```
Broker1       FOREX       CURRENCY_BUY       $0.00             $5500000.00
```

and

```
Broker1       STOCKMARKET STOCKS_BUY         $0.00             $9500000.00
```

The thing is that it will be executed thru plsql batch on unix, so it must be a single query.

Any ideas and/or suggestions are very appreciated!

Thanks

P.S.

Its oracle 11gr2, with read-only role.

Comment: why it cuts off very first line saying "Hello guys"???

Comment: Stackoverflow automatically filters out those kinds of greetings. They're unnecessary and detract from the problem at hand. Just dive right into the meat of your question when you're here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, is there a reason you can't create a MARKET table?  That will obviously be the most straight-forward solution.  However, if you don't have DB access and have to hack it into your query, you could do something like this:

```
WITH m AS (
    select 'CURRENCY_SELL' as tran_type, 'FOREX' as market_name from dual
    UNION ALL
    select 'CURRENCY_BUY' as tran_type, 'FOREX' as market_name from dual
    UNION ALL
    select 'STOCKS_SELL' as tran_type, 'STOCKMARKET' as market_name from dual
    UNION ALL
    select 'STOCKS_BUY' as tran_type, 'STOCKMARKET' as market_name from dual
)
select
    b.company, m.tran_type, m.market_name, 
    nvl(v.curr_month, 0) as curr_month,
    nvl(v.all_mnth, 0) as all_mnth
from
    m
cross join
    (select distinct b.company from brokers) b
left join (
    select b.COMPANY, tt.TRAN_TYPE, b.CURR_MONTH, b.ALL_MNTH
    from    BROKERS b, TRAN_TYPE_CD_EXPL tt
    where   b.TRAN_TYPE_CD = tt.TRAN_TYPE_CD
) v
on v.company = b.company and v.tran_type = m.tran_type;
```

First, I've done a cross join of companies with the inline Market view - You'll get a combination of all those records for each company, even if they do not exist together in the Brokers table.  I've performed a left outer join to get your numbers, so it plugs in 0 if a NULL value comes back (no corresponding record).

This may not be exactly right (I don't know how you partition your months, for example), but should point you in the correct direction.

UPDATE

OK, so if I understand correctly, you want to limit the "empty" rows to transaction types where the broker has had at least one transaction within the same market.

I'm going to assume that the "BROKERS" is a view of the current month - so if there's a record in the table, it's happened this month.

So we could remove the cross join and do this instead:

```
WITH m AS (
    select 9 as tran_type_cd, 'FOREX' as market_name from dual
    UNION ALL
    select 10, 'FOREX' as market_name from dual
    UNION ALL
    select 1, 'STOCKMARKET' from dual
    UNION ALL
    select 2, 'STOCKMARKET' from dual
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 3, 'CONTRACTS' from dual
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 4, 'CONTRACTS' from dual
)
select
    bm.company, tt.tran_type, m.market_name, 
    nvl(v.curr_month, 0) as curr_month,
    nvl(v.all_mnth, 0) as all_mnth
from
    (select distinct b.company, m.market_name
     from brokers b
     join m on m.tran_type_cd = b.tran_type_cd) bm
join
    m on m.market_name = bm.market_name
join
    TRAN_TYPE_CD_EXPL tt on tt.tran_type_cd = m.tran_type_cd
left join (
    select b.COMPANY, b.tran_type_cd, b.CURR_MONTH, b.ALL_MNTH
    from    BROKERS b
) v
on v.company = bm.company and v.tran_type_cd = m.tran_type_cd;
```

The view "bm" (great acronym choice, I know!) should give you a distinct list of markets tied to the company for the month.  I then have joined back to the market view to get all transaction types associated with that market.  As before, I've used a left join to fill in the empty rows with 0, if there's not a matching record in the Brokers table.

Here's the SQL Fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2f16e/13

Comment: Dan thanks a lot, i just implemented your code, the thing is that after cross join it returns all the possible combinations, i need to narrow down it to the particular "group". What i mean is here for illusrtrating purpose i put a broker with 3 market types (FOREX, CONTRACTS and STOCKMARKET) but in reality some of the brokers can have only 1 tran_type during a month lets say 'CURRENCY_SELL' so in this case i just need to populate report with the missing 'CURRENCY_BUY' only but not the all of the available market types.

Answer (score 2):

First part of the query is exactly like yours, only with market as inline table. Second part adds missing rows by joining market twice to add missing rows, and then substracts rows already present in first part.

```
WITH Market AS (
  SELECT 9 TRAN_TYPE_CD, 'FOREX' Market FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 10, 'FOREX' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'STOCKMarket'  FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'STOCKMarket' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'CONTRACTS' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'CONTRACTS' FROM dual
)
SELECT b.COMPANY, Market.Market, tt.TRAN_TYPE_CD_EXPLD, 
       b.CURR_MONTH, b.ALL_MONTH
  FROM BROKERS b 
 INNER JOIN TRAN_TYPE_CD_EXPL tt
    ON b.TRAN_TYPE_CD = tt.TRAN_TYPE_CD
 INNER JOIN Market
    ON b.TRAN_TYPE_CD = Market.TRAN_TYPE_CD
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT b.COMPANY, Market.Market, tt.TRAN_TYPE_CD_EXPLD, 
         0 CURR_MONTH, 0 ALL_MONTH
    FROM BROKERS b 
   INNER JOIN Market
      ON b.TRAN_TYPE_CD = Market.TRAN_TYPE_CD
   INNER JOIN Market Market2
      ON Market.Market = Market2.Market
     AND Market.TRAN_TYPE_CD <> Market2.TRAN_TYPE_CD
   INNER JOIN TRAN_TYPE_CD_EXPL tt
      ON Market2.TRAN_TYPE_CD = tt.TRAN_TYPE_CD
 MINUS
 SELECT b.COMPANY, Market.Market, tt.TRAN_TYPE_CD_EXPLD, 
        0 CURR_MONTH, 0 ALL_MONTH
   FROM BROKERS b 
  INNER JOIN TRAN_TYPE_CD_EXPL tt
     ON b.TRAN_TYPE_CD = tt.TRAN_TYPE_CD
  INNER JOIN Market
     ON b.TRAN_TYPE_CD = Market.TRAN_TYPE_CD
)
```

And here is [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f957f/28) to test results.

Answer (score 1):

not sure where you're going to get your data for the all_mnth, so you should figure that out first.  Let us know and then joining that in woth zero values should be easy.  below is my test query up through problem 1 (similar to @Dan A. I "created" a market "table"):

```
with brokers as
(
select 'Broker1' company, 9 tran_type_cd, 1000  curr_mnth, 1500000 all_mnth from dual union
select 'Broker1' company, 3 tran_type_cd, 50000 curr_mnth, 2500000 all_mnth from dual union
select 'Broker1' company, 4 tran_type_cd, 80000 curr_mnth, 8500000 all_mnth from dual union
select 'Broker1' company, 1 tran_type_cd, 35000 curr_mnth, 3500000 all_mnth from dual 
)
, tran_type_cd_expl as
(
select 1  TRAN_TYPE_CD, 'STOCKS_SELL'  TRAN_TYPE_CD_EXPLD from dual union
select 2  TRAN_TYPE_CD, 'STOCKS_BUY'  TRAN_TYPE_CD_EXPLD from dual union
select 3  TRAN_TYPE_CD, 'GOLD_SELL'  TRAN_TYPE_CD_EXPLD from dual union
select 4  TRAN_TYPE_CD, 'GOLD_BUY'  TRAN_TYPE_CD_EXPLD from dual union
select 5  TRAN_TYPE_CD, 'SILVER_SELL'  TRAN_TYPE_CD_EXPLD from dual union
select 6  TRAN_TYPE_CD, 'SILVER_BUY'  TRAN_TYPE_CD_EXPLD from dual union
select 7  TRAN_TYPE_CD, 'COPPER_SELL'  TRAN_TYPE_CD_EXPLD from dual union
select 8  TRAN_TYPE_CD, 'COPPER_BUY'  TRAN_TYPE_CD_EXPLD from dual union
select 9  TRAN_TYPE_CD, 'CURRENCY_SELL'  TRAN_TYPE_CD_EXPLD from dual union
select 10  TRAN_TYPE_CD, 'CURRENCY_BUY'  TRAN_TYPE_CD_EXPLD from dual 
)
, market as
(
select 'CURRENCY_BUY'  tran_type_cd_expld, 'FOREX'       market from dual union
select 'CURRENCY_SELL' tran_type_cd_expld, 'FOREX'       market from dual union
select 'GOLD_BUY'      tran_type_cd_expld, 'CONTRACTS'   market from dual union
select 'GOLD_SELL'     tran_type_cd_expld, 'CONTRACTS'   market from dual union
select 'STOCKS_BUY'    tran_type_cd_expld, 'STOCKMARKET' market from dual union
select 'STOCKS_SELL'   tran_type_cd_expld, 'STOCKMARKET' market from dual 
)

select company, market, t.tran_type_cd_expld tran_type, curr_mnth, all_mnth
from brokers b, tran_type_cd_expl t, market m
where b.tran_type_cd = t.tran_type_cd
and t.tran_type_cd_expld = m.tran_type_cd_expld
;
```

Comment: Roger, data in all_mnth field is populated to the table from batch, actually in very funny way - it calculates the sum of particular tran_type for this particular broker ... and never used elsewhere)))

Comment: ok. please give a sample of the table where the all_mnth calcualtion comes from. The idea is to do that sum (if simple SQL) then union that in (excluding rows/types that have monthly amount) with the results of your main query where you have montly ammount.

Comment: Roger, it comes from the same table - from CURR_MNTH column, the difference is that for illustratuing purpose i call it as CURR_MONTH, but this is actually MNTH_SALES column with another column MONTH_ID equal to current, so batch populates its like sum(MNTH_SALES) for particular broker.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can add the additional rows with [Subquery Factoring](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2077142) (like CTE in SQL Server). If you don't get an answer, I can try to update with code later this evening.